# Oversized jqPlot charts in some browsers

Tags: charts, primefaces, jqplot

The charts, especially when exportedToImage are oversized/scaled - discovered on a MacBook in Chrome and Safari - while testing for an issue with Primefaces (Pf uses JqPlot for charts)

See on the [jqplot test-page](https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/issues/119), but it is also reproducible on Linux/Ubuntu with a [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser))-based browser when opening developer tools and selecting any mobile-device (in this case I set it to "responsive")

!! - reload the page after opening dev-tools !! - at any resolution the image keeps getting oversized. To disable the effect, just close dev-tools and reload. Now the image looks correct again.

There was an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/issues/119), but it was closed.
Also the [showcase of PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/export.xhtml) using this library works.

How can that be? I've checked this with all my available devices to rule that out - but it's somehow strange - can someone also reproduce this?

What does developer tools and Chromium on Mac do to get these results? - ignoring media-queries? I've also experimented with that, no success.

[image: oversized / overscaled images]

Answer (score 2):

If your read that jqPlot ticket you posted here it has a solution in it: https://github.com/jqPlot/jqPlot/issues/119

PrimeFaces 8.0 Showcase has the following manually patched fix applied from that ticket:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4655

That is why the PrimeFaces showcase does not exhibit the issue if you read through that ticket it is a two line fix applied to the JQPlot code.

Comment: thx, that makes it clear, did not realize that this is fixed in 8.0 which will come out soon.... thank you very much!